# Hadoop distcp to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, distcp

I am using Hadoop distcp command to move data from hdfs to s3. Recently after hadoop cdh to cdp upgrade I am facing a difference in -update option. Previously-update will move files with same file name, same size but with different content. now it ignores the file if name and size are same. Is there anyways to move achieve this kind of update in cloudera cdp version?

`hadoop distcp -pu -update -delete hdfspath s3bucket`

Comment: I don't think CDP matters. If the Hadoop version was upgraded, then you may need to review the changelog for distcp command. I think it compares checksums, though, not only name/size

Comment: I doubt that too but I saw hortonworks docs checks filename and size for -update https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/DistCp.html#Command_Line_Options

Comment: That's not Hortwonworks docs. That's just Apache source. Read the first row - _when `-update` is specified, status updates will **not** be synchronized unless the file sizes also differ_. So, if you want to ignore the sizes, then remove `-update`

Comment: Also, Amazon has their own [version of DistCP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html), optimized for S3

Comment: Yes right hortonworks docs points to that link and cloudera points to a different version of distcp doc which says checksum will be considered

Comment: Okay, well, the documentation you've linked to is version 2.5.2, but before hortonworks was acquired, it used at least version 2.7.3... So what hadoop core version are you at now? And what do the docs look like for it? Otherwise, sounds like you simply need `-override` flag

Comment: hadoop version is 3.1.1 and the distcp doc says it uses size/blocksize/checksum to compare https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html#Command_Line_Options. but that didnt happen to us. and what is -override flag?

Comment: Typo. Meant `-overwrite`

Comment: ok -overwrite actually works. i am trying to transfer only modified file or new file

Comment: Okay.. So you are saying that when you modify a file, then it ends up the exact same size and name? Making `-update` not work? A "new file" would never have the same name, so those would get copied fine